# How to use my own password hasher

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-2.0

I tried to follow cake's documentation do create my own password hasher, but it seems that the authentication component is not using it.

This is my code:

```
class AppController extends Controller {
  public $helpers = array('Html', 'Form', 'Session');

  public $components = array(
    'Session',
    'Auth' => array(
        'authenticate' => array(
            'Form' => array(
                'passwordHasher' => array(
                    'className' => 'Fake64'),
                'fields' => array('username' => 'user_login',
                                  'password' => 'user_senha')
            )
        ),            
        'loginRedirect' => array('controller' => 'tickets', 'action' => 'index'),
        'logoutRedirect' => array('controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'login')
    )
  );

  public function beforeFilter() {
    $this->Auth->allow('index');
  }
}
```

And in my UsersController:

```
public function login() {
    if ($this->request->is('post')) {
        $hasher = new Fake64PasswordHasher();
        debug($this->request->data['User']['password']);
        debug($hasher->hash($this->request->data['User']['password']));
        debug($hasher->check($this->request->data['User']['password'], $hasher->hash($this->request->data['User']['password'])));
        if ($this->Auth->login()) {
            return $this->redirect($this->Auth->redirectUrl());
        }
        $this->Session->setFlash(__('Invalid username or password, try again'));
    }
}
```

These debug messages show I have the correct password, the correct hash and that the check function is returning true. Still, I can't login.

Any ideas?

EDIT:

By the way, I tried to use: `$this->Session->setFlash($this->authError);`

and no message is printed.

Comment: Please always mention your exact CakePHP version! Also it's advised to use the general [tag:cakephp] tag, the version specific ones have practically no followers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your form data fields do not match the form authentication fields configuration. You've configured `user_login` for the username, and `user_senha` for the password, but according to the debug calls in your `login()` action you are submitting the password field as `password` (not sure about the username field, it might use the wrong name too).

So either change or remove (it uses `username` and `password` by default) the fields config, or change the input field names.

Comment: Great! Thanks. I had completely misunderstood the fields config docs.